# Why is a column going into the next row when there are only 12 columns?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid, grid-system

I have a row with 4 columns that are each 3 wide, which adds up to the 12 that are supposed the be in a row, but for some reason the last one is still going onto a new row. Any idea how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container text-center">    
  <h3>Welcome to "Ender's Super Cool Recomendations" where I, Ender, give you, the reader, super cool recomendations for MOVIES you should watch!</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>Shows</h4>
          <div class="well">
            <p><a href="heartstopper2.html">Heartstopper</a></p>
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="img-responsive" alt="Heartstopper poster">
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>Upbeat (Comedy, Romnace, Action, ect.) Movies</h4>
          <div class="well">
            <p><a href=""></a></p>
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>Horror Movies</h4>
          <div class="well">
            <p><a href="beforeiwake.html">Before I Wake</a></p>
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODk3MWFiMWQtODAwNi00MjBkLTg4YTctMGFhZTg4MDI5NmU4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTA4NjE0NjEy._V1_.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Before I Wake movie Poster">
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h4>Sad Movies</h4>
          <div class="well">
            <p><a href="dps.html">Dead Poets Society</a></p>
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEhUTExIVFhUXFRcXFhcVFxUXFRUVFRUXFhUVFRcYHSggGBolGxUXITIhJSkrOi4wFx8zODMtNyg5LisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGy0lHyUtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIAREAuQMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAAABwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwj/xABREAABAwIDAwcECw0GBgMAAAABAAIRAyEEEjEFQVEHEyIyYXGRBoGxsxQWQlJTVHOTodHSIyQ0RGJygpKytMHT8BUzdKKj4RclQ2OEwzWD8f/EABoBAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAQIEBQb/xAA1EQABAwEECAQFBQEBAQAAAAABAAIRAwQSITETQVFhcZGx0TKBwfAUIpKh0iMzUuHxBWI0/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDhqCC6lybeQdHaVGtUqVqtM06gYBTyQQWB0nMDxVXODRJV2tBzPvmFy1Bd+PIvhfjWI8KX2Ug8jWF+NV/1aX2Us2hgzPXsmaIb+Q/JcEQXeDyN4X41X+bo/UlN5GMKfxut83R+pAtFM5Hr2UmgBrPIfkuCo13k8jWF+NVvm6P1I28jOFP43V+bofUgV6cxI+/ZGhG08h+S4LKC70eRnDfGqvzVH6kByMYf45V+aoI07No+/ZRom7TyH5LgqC7y7kZw4/HKvzVBJHI3h/jdX5mgq/E0v5D79lOhG/kPyXCEF3g8jeH+N1fmqCMcjWHifZdX5qgp+Jp/yH37I0I2nkPyXBpRLvI5HMN8aq/N0PqTn/BfDfG6vzdD6kNtNN2RH37INFo1nkPyXAkF3v8A4NYb43V+bofUjHIxhfjdb5uh9SPiKe0ffso0I2nkPyXA0F3o8jWF+NV/m6H1JY5G8L8ZxH6tH7Kj4ql/IffspNEb+Q/JcCQXfhyM4X43iPCl9lUnlzybUMDgquJp4iu59Mshr+bynPVYwzDQdHKwrtJgH3yVdEBmTyH5LjiCer9Y959KZTktwgkILvnIE771xPy7PVBcEK7vyDH71xPy1P6aQSbQYpk+8wmUhPMdCtnszGP5yoHF0ZqmUOJcHBtaoJbPVgZW5Rug705jcQOcaKjyymWEghxYC+RZzxEGNBN5drFp1S6KmFw9MS6VuDAGpnZ9R5pNL5Lr3IhzhJDXOECCWwSIFyVE2DiXufUDnEgaXzAHnKoMk9UkBvR3AA71YtqtNgQe4g7yPSCPMU5CaKoxKgtwCbDiaz2yY5qmQN0l9QE/QPBRMfiKlKoXAksbSJe0CXRmI5xnEt3jeJ3gA2LH9qWao08/+6vpGgSqlpyRYR002EmSWNJPE5RdKdcG8enzIZ9yZqOukPqSpa3UqXZ+0az3sY6YJ1gj+4aadeT21cscQSrLadUtoVXNMFtJ5BGoIYSCPOlucBqQO8xwH8R4hPsEBAfeIMKbkCEslQdm4sOa4Zw5zalQG4JaBVeGggaWH0J9r7oqtUXvpr2b78LKmkhuCm7io9bFhtakHPDWubUsSAHODqQaL6npGB2qbjqpbTeQYIY4g8CAUyx8GJvrE3juTwqIZVAHvbKhzcUzRqEtadbD0KFhtqvNaCDzTyWU3dGC+nJdvnpRU1AEUhHWViU1WfAkmBxNh4oY6JVi2UnalQii8h2U5bOEdE7jexTGGrVjWAqENHNu6Lbglr2DnOyZMDcNbm05miTzkK4qACFBZim9sVslPNnDYImXZM4vLA/3LjqO6N8rLcqtXNsfEG9+YN9b16Wo4rTOxl4WZ5Vj/wApxHfR/eKadZqt+o0BUq0y1pledMR1j3n0plPYjrHvPpTK7QWGp43cSjK7jyHu+9sT8pS9SVw1dv5ED9xxXylD1Tlmtv7DuHqE6z+o6OXR3ORBxSoSYXmJK6ghVFLZAZVFQVH6yWkuLT06j/fW/vIjSJtdFR2K4R981SA7N0rmOickyJbIJgz1uAhWNSAQnGAq4tDwqmk2FCfsKXFwrPbL3uIEgODyTld0rxJg23cIIq7GkMaKrwWB1wXAuzGRJDgYEC07lZSUdMlN+IcdaXogqilsGo0hzsQ4kB4FjHSmHOGaJHRMCB0QN0oM2AR+MVOqGk3DjBJzE5utcieBI1unDtmq4vDKAIY8sk1GtktAJgHddKGKxPxcfONTiXzmObe6oAwjXyKPE7HDwzNVd0GlrSC4GCaTukQ7pXpaGZzdiSzZByMHP1JYOtLpcemZd0rmXA/ojQWSKmMxA1oN+dYnKeKxJFsO0j5VqX+oMJH1N7qYZE48j2RYbYRD2PNd7i10xBEi3QMO6oIkDtOsqPV8nZJ+7PElxIEgGWhokZrkRM75NospjcVivi7fnW/UmTtHEAxzDJ4c81X/AFIGI5t7qAG7+TuydfsAOyHnXtLWtbLdXAOl8k++Bc08MxIgwUzT2EWty8+89JpvmvlDgc3SkzmmAQAWggazLdjsUBJwzbCf71v1JeDrc/Rp1QIFRjXgbwHtDgD4qXB4GfIg7diht0n/AFVbdhwIFd+7pG77ZRJM9boAzGpPGEK+wszS01nX1kSBBa4FoJsZbr+U7jaybYwifWgws/xDxrWjQNOpQP7FOvPPIDSA0yBmNPLmJBnrDP2EmNVNw1EtYGlxdAiTqe09qlUYIRVGKKlRzmiVDWtacFGOEIMgrOcp5d/ZWJnSaH7xTWkbiYN1n+VKsHbJxEe+oevpplgc012x7wKi03rhnd1C88YjrHvPpTeU8E5iOse8+lIzlenC5NTxu4nqkLtfIj/c4v8APw300qn1Lii7TyHHoY0duE+mlW+pZbd+w/h6hOs2fmOjl0N7ygahCW5qW2kvKQSV2JACrMRVkqbhMRICTUwwMpzB4eEQcld7mFilNKRWrcE7CbqsGqcYuws4icVmBQa49JoP/MRqAdaXarnHYPm6bqlECm+m0vEAhtTKMxY9rbOBAIvcTYhUr6uWTe20ATAJgCkJJjQX1Vhitoucx7KQLnPaWh0HI3MMpc50RaZjUxom1HEVDsk8E2mHFrCP6zTeGxNN+IfUNMkPw2HeIpuqEZucN8rTBiBfgrnD1mNp5mjKzpEy0siCcxLSARcE6dqptnVadGs9lw1tChTaSDBNPPN4ibgnvQ2jtJtaKTA4hzgHmCG5GgOeLi4NmfpGNDFXu14ofTvOgDDDlA6IsDXc2uHl0jEsLonqPZdjY3fciAe1h4o2gHHEuaD96jUA/wDXP1I9p0BzZexgDmFr2ZWgSWGcpyj3TcwQdXb7LFQhwYcK0A5XRPPF2UmNYIsovF2IThEExqjkR6QBwKe2nW5ksLLU3u5pzB1czgSx7Ro0y0g8c3YleTWI+9MOOFCl6tqiY8GsW9FzaVM84XOBaXva0hjWg3gTJJHCJ3P+TjJwuH+Qperarl50Z2yOjlmc1uE5wevvygKS8uzSluZm3KU6nAQpuCRcxgq1/WAhSokBNVHp81woGIfeVSoBEBRTBccUzi6J1WY5QWxsvEd9D17Fs3XAWT5SqcbMxH51D1zFqsVO7aWefQorvmiQd3ULgeI6x7z6Uyna/WPefSm16oLh1PG7iUS7TyDG2O/8P9jELiy7DyKVsrMae3B+rxCzW0xQcd3qE6zNvGN46OXV60JLVEp4nMpNJ68reBMrqlhbgU4GBOghRqlWCE7qUxrglkHMpIaSUshOMsg9qpdwUXsVkaNZ3OmmCAH4msHEgEw2g14jzhSqm0BTcWPaHOLQWZRGcucWBpEmDI10iTuUOmycSBv9lYjTX8GYplbZ+Uc61rnuZUa946z3Ma1zXBs78riQ0bxxKfUAdVg7+pWukGaNt7WOGN4xj5R7wRUw1U/9VoduaKYNPuMnMe+R3BVVXE1C5jQAxxqPpvBGaHNaHSDaQdQeB7FqqJpVG8617SyJzTYDfM6RvnRZvaLGur03uHRfUdE2zNZQLQ4jdLpjsDeKSGQZdq3LRQqSS0jUdWuD78lLPOBoGe87mAHdxJ7fFN7LxD6rA5z4cXPFmtjo1HNFu5vFS8K2m02iBBIBmJtPZp9CTsNjDhw6QINYnu56oVLcW/0N6hxaGkxrHqiwtQ1WOfnAjOH08o6EBwDdZDtDJkHcBNpHk1UjDUPkKXq2qJtag1obUYQHkhsg/wB6wmHNIHWAEuB3ZZ0lHsJ8Yeh8jS9W1XL4pyP5Do5Ic0OdhlB8sufHsr2viLKJzpOieotzBSadEJYl2aXLWCFW5nJFQOi6tWUQSmcYyyCMJV21ReAhRaFUBpnVZjlHrE7Nr/nUPXNWjbS1Wf5SqOXZdY8X0B/qtT7A4m0MHHoVW0XRTdvjqFwOv1j3n0puE5W6x7z6U3K9UFwX+I8SkrrnI8PueO/OwXq8QuRrsXItTzMxw7cH6vELLbv2H8D6LTYzDgf/AEOjltG4khT8Pi4aq3EtAMJVKoNF5EOXonUw4KcXPqOsFN9k5IBStmuAGir9qE5wSnhoAlY/G+5GAVyx0iUsVFXYHGQId4qVmBcpxzSHUyDBWfoVWtdVcWtn2U8Ne+wYXUqehGhdYbpnzGSMRUzFrIt1iXPgOIBygC5sRe2o13Qm45lN1djhM13EtcyrBaadOCC2m4OFiEzS2hTpdR5dIGYOZXEODQ2WnmzIgNEH3s71qrWesXEhp3YHGfJTRqU7kEid6drYikHyaDOezEGeIaHc5niS2CLxqY1UbHHnOk9jH9JjRM2zva09aeM+ZNY/FUnRUDjzmYkgUq2WC0NLJyTHRBmNRpFlHOPaRoR0mHqVj1Xtcf8Ap8Al6CvI+R0cHLZTq0IDg4Tx36tym4NsOexjabYcRAkFxyggmO/6FJ2W14LmhrWhj8sAvAPRa6badZN7L2nSbUe50Q5+aSyvmDcrWm3NXNjv3qwobWwzXVDnPSqZhFOtpkY2/Q1lpU/C1oJunVqKVUtlOSJHNFTYxzTlpta/K7no1YQDIJ90SdOIv3veTmHDsJQP/YperamqW2KAFeXk53FzYp1iY5imyD0LGWHxCsfJno4TDgiCKFMEGxBDACCOKu6i4M+dpGIznY7asjq0ulp94IxShTGRF1BxlbKU0NotNisbSAYTzTc8SrF740TDnZkeQZTBlV3OEEAHerEluaimyZhTarAFkuU15/sysD8JQ9aFqX6SSspyl1J2ZW+UoetCfYY+JbG/oVFUfpny6hcDqanvKQl1NT50lepXEf4ikLrvIvXyMxx7cJ6vELkS63yOdTG/+J+xXWW3GKDzuK02QAvAP8m9HLZYrEF57VK2bg3EzuSW0Rm0Vn7JFMABeZa4TivQVCQLrFaiABCaxeEFQdyLB1Q4JeIqFgJTAdepc0AtdAzTeGwIAgqQyhlKj4fFklOc/LoUhwOSlwfJlTZTVUtBa06ukNHGBJ+hIpvO9LIBvFxp2XB9ICZ8rswkEEZKjfWa8dUxIGrbSARN9L6qI8tbcg3mNLwSDvjcrSvTbm8N53AARe2g8E8cIwgdEWmOzNEx3wFmLKU+FahVqtAxwVXRxrWE2NiBq3eSOPZ51bYTGtcWiDLtLWgZ5Pmyf5m8Ul2z2QTlud97nt47/FSsHgWtAj0nt+0fFPpsbOSVVeXCSUHncjqRCk82AkvaFbRwlXws/iOsojsLN5VnjG3gaqBTw7wZKyFsGV1KbpbnCIV3NsiawlwKFfEDQBKdWgWSyTtV4MYDNWwpgNklYzlPA/s2r8rQ9YFpcNWt0tFneVBwOznx8LQ9YuhY3B1Zkb+hWGq0hpB2jqF58fqe9GidqjXp1xDmm11/kSpZhjB/hf2a65AuvcibyG4wjhhfRXWS2/sP4FabL4sNo9V1s4JsQBdUeNpZDc3Vxhq3EqDtXI+b3C8w5rXtkYFdeg5zXwclBwuMeDZW9TGtfSMmCoexajBYi6b25h2xLT4KzTdbKa8NdUDSI3qVserJUjF1MtRvaqrYtQDKrLaN6jFLD8kKlRv624gqUKsW1Qq4nm7kWP0J4UN6VUpAgh2hTmNIzWMubOKq84fUsrgUoCz0CnUsZWhp1QWg8UuniTKZaRAbGSB0TVKvfKdQjfWy2KgYoOcQ9viqvqEHDNLZTvYHmrZ5TdRyaFXo3UVtQuMxZS6r91VtM5osU0a70hrs4hHiKdu1JwmFMSkm8XxC0iA2SUKmz25e1V9agWkcFYYjEZSJS60OanOFNwwGKu172wTkVEZlcszymCNn1B/3aHrFqMJh7rPcqzQNm1PlqH7ZTLACazSd/QqtdwGA2jqF54KVHYko5XqlwEhdg5EACMZPDC+iuuPrr3IkGkYzMYH3r4xXWa2CaLuBWqy+LzHquk1aYYetY6JqtkI1jilbTHZ3KqGF6JLnDuXlXCDgF3qYkAkqU7F80DlAM71Hr44vs4AKKaN5aSO9SaeF6IzT2FUl2RKdDB8yc2d7kzof4q72iAH0z2rN7PpOh5EkAq2xOKLhSjd1uzRWFSARwS6rJqAjeFpQ6yS6nmHek0jm7LKHt3arcHh6td8ltNuaBq46NaO0kgLcGF2C4+Sq8bRbTqHutPapuEa4FpkxwXLaHl/i8XWApYJlQgF2QOfmyi56Wkx2Lo+A2lUrYejVpjo1DItBaLiHcCCCD3Kj7G+kZd35rYK4qNAB4zw1Kxr0XZ8024dikU3AiBoorMSdDeNU5RDoJNgdEprhekJbgYxRsomTqQnhT4J6m6AjJnRNDGwll5JUOqyNUqnUgQjxhmBCaokTBSHODamCuMWyUzjMNnCi4SrBDd8wrmBCpdq0yxzag03/AMFD23fm5p9J9/5D5KXXoZTO86LI8pjSNnPn4ah+2thhsRn6R7lluVb/AOOf8tQ/bK12QMdaGvbv6FKcXABrto6hedkIQSpXplxEhdg5EqIe3GAjRuGPniuuPrs/II2fZg/Jw3/uWW2CaLhuK0WcwZ3j1XQalIRJGmu9EynSM2nffcVaOw2UyVW4/DibGCvNta4LrNc12EqqxdZrTDBY+eO5StjS9rnEnLERvUGtiDTDiMpgaqx8lXjm3ONiXb+Ci7hitFQwzBTdmU2c2+BbtUXCYchrqlsodMHeArHZNCz5v0iAN0QEnE0ctKo2LG9uHBQ6l4Sdn9pAq/M4DWRyUGl5UNyc5kgSQ3WXXgQq7ymb7Nwdag52V1RoIHvS1wc0nsloUDatd1KnLG5naNYBZg7Sl+RGHq4tzs1gLVHaHuHaVppCs8gsOvD36q9WnQpt+YQq/YLXYSiyiTSYcsOLWlxNQC7rWdfitPs+sBhWCnIaczzmgOJe9znEAWEuJMdq0G0/JujWiwa4AAGJFhAzCb232PaqDFY1mBq06GLoh9J8ilimMJAMkmnUYASyPfZjIMxYx0aliqPkXo1ysZtlNzWwMRq95pOBxMSNbwVe1XZmwP8A8VBtjZ5w7ucYc1F8Oa6QRBvE7+w7wrjZuODgLWhcrRmi803p73Co0VGYqXh3WgmY3o8PUJeR4KPX2th6THc5VYyNQSAfBVbPKClWDKlF4c0gxuII1BGqY8BrQ4ZJLWFziIVrtJ7jOSOjqioMlt9+kKDgyXNMHWSncDWgBwMgEjiVnAvuvEZprmhjYGpP0swdDhbcU5tCi1zIneCg+vzgMjQ69yhOxjS5zJBIExu7u9Ne3Ry0YhUaS4h2RSdnEh+U6fxWc5VyfYNUbuew/wC2rR+26NMtc+q1jXRGYxftVHynY6k/A12MeHObVw7nAaQ59iDoR3Jv/PY4PAjWY5GUVXAuBnHDqFwFHCI6ol6VcZEurcke22YOljar+GGa209ItrkehcqK1exa2XCVzEzXwYj/AOrFJVVt5pG5NpmAeI9V0TbfKiCxraeZr7EuhpBjUEbgVQHlExAMuc17YMtIiQTqCFgcWYe6+/vidyZqVS7doPoWdtjp7E34h+pdG2lyhU30TTpUixztSSOjxgqDszlHxNIsa2HNY0th2jhxdxIWGZpJEjfdGQJtYeKsLJRAiEG01HGSVvjymYqHhjsrnkGQBDCBBDQdxhHS5SMa9uQw5sHM52pPEuFgJ3LnjzeyddU+5hs6OJI42EE/Sp+EpR4Qo09QYgrX4XyyrU8zXVA8OnLJByndcbu9dg5GalSphKtWrlzPrkANizBSplsxv6ZPnXIPIrySNSo+piqNUU6Qk0zTdzlUkEBrWmLflEjTw6dydUhsx2Lo167W0XOZVoZyAIyuD+l7pwa2mDGuWd6GMoteboEq1Q1jTF4mFrPLTytobNo87UBeS4NYxsAucQTcnRoAklctwXlXtDatdzHspjDEc4A6mQGc3cOZU9y/eCTBiN60Pl3tLZe02GgMXzdVjmuZUg825wtGYjKNSMxiJ3hUOI8ohhqYpl5rObDei/7jYC7spuZEjf2orVnMgASmWOyacmPe/wAv9hbPycwDqLXsrPp1KY+6s5p00qThna7K0uIYCMrstozcRKyO3aG18UX1sFRLKDJaObxNKo+vBdme0tcZI0iZ0iSoHkhtR+IdVwRYGUK3O1azqbMpJeBmBeN0Ekb7DdZU/lJ5S4nCYiphsO91Cgx2amylDOjViqHTr7s2EAaJYYHPxG/FWrB1MEE45Ybft595WUxNWo6o8VJL5OfnTlc1wMHNniDNrpX9ovYQ4OyxcFptI4EWKvMd5VOxjGeyH/dWAt53Ixr3tmQHlojo3AMDrX4rUcm2Fc5zqtUseA0ABwmM2a97TlaDN7O8HVqjabS4jJZ6dB1QgtIx5jiOhEg7Vk8H5S4mSedcGOBc6DE5QXEW003LXeRfkW6rnrbQbWeSA5tLO9pM3zWcNdwBEKHtjyPwtcV30MWxuJDnkUA3KwtzQ2nJABffLIm7gL6rbeSG12uwtE84C5rBTqE3y1A3V06dkxMLPUeGsDmYTEx7yWmlZ33y2oDOoH08uqxHl5tR+zq1OlhaldlF9EVBTqOc4scXPaRL5JHZJgyspS2lWkuJI0zXMm1j3Lc8pOyOdDqtfnG1KbPuTmljaDwRnzGkZLSXSDDuB005cahIg3cDpNyP4p9Noc2detYbQIcQr7EYgOIzExqZvl7VJw2ONTB4tpNmHDZfzefOnYs5MmGugRljh3q42S77yxgmYGFM8JraK4ZCTQbdqN4hZE6pSJ+pQTlcpC1WyqBfg8SA5rYrYMy7Q/csXZZVaXBtnBYj5fB+pxagqw8B4j1VcJiDlJMg9kHWVEDy069lk49pbqZKaiIO5AColGqSb/7JLTeLnu1UzZ2DNZ4ZIa0Xc46NaNTG88BvJWgDmtGWkSGiwv1j749p/il1KoZxXSsP/OdapdN1o1xMnYMR5n1WXfQcD0gW/nAhTMPgdHOIIsQLwe/Qq12q2k8USM2ZgcHtJlrjMjLwN7+ZQXulVNUkCFrZ/wA5tOo4vxAwAOveY+w5rpeB8u6LmDnM1PLAIFz+hABcPp79VjvKTynNVnNszDK9zs3RGeXE5iGgRutFgFSSnaNJrhLtPBZ6dNlN16Frq03V23GmDB9nmruvQfQDG4mkxzi0vaA+zswMOeGm4kncJhQMNkJObosZLnBoMkC8CNO86Tqm8TXLjJO4eYAQAOFgntg7Up0Huc+jzhggdKIBGhGhB39hKkyRKa1rKIDWxO1bfZ/lZzlFxFN4p0mi3RbTa1rZgQ46CNAsnyjY1lUYJ7XMP3q0ODXNc5rpkio4XLr3ngdFV1sa4moW9AVC7MxshkOmWxwVXjxIbCijSDXyPeCx21odRO7ZxHp1S9i4ijTr0n12F9Fr2uqMES9oMlt7QdD2SuweQ21aWLrYms6pq9pyxlBAzAQNwgNgcFxGlSLtPFWlDajmOhhNNuVrYad41ce0mTO6U+009I0tH9LmWT5TedgDgDxUzyjB6YnNFUy7jBIzfxWy5LNm1axdiBWZSpUSBULhmzjrFpZvERqdSIusPUIc2NZTOErVKBJp1XtkQYJAcJBhw0IsNeAUMgNurpW+i6pVFQZQBw9grtPlLgMLWotpudVqPlwpvBbTLcx6IAAhwA99NpJVH5QvwGD2dWw9KkzM9uVsw6o55iHl5ky3rdkQFX1/Lqk3CkNaXV3MjTosndJvE6xqsTVxXPCahOfNOcbuwjSNPALMxrnEF2AByGCTUohxcGwXRmemwKrp9E6gjjulXuxXThMbYfi2m/7us/WEOIMn+tyvNhfgeN7sL69dE5SuPTaRUE5yOqzL9T3oQg/U96JSoOaStLgyfYOJj4fBeqxazS0dD8BxH+IwXqMWoKuPAeI9VTB83KKUAk/QrKkK52c4Mpl295+hu7xR1scQLhIrVo0MRpEAR2AKudVzG+iyhl9xK777SbNRbSYcRhqidZ5yrEvkD+rpBSM6J71ACY6oCMU1XbYqRsh1nX3/AMEy0S0njKc2YOt3qzh8pCRZ/wD6GP2g+qlVyoZJsRqpNR2qZlVatNcy5JqViN11GfVI4bxftCkVErB4nmqjKkZsrgYOjoNx59FduGpYq5cc3QOm0pmk6Gi14/ohN1MPN9PrU7GYh1V76jus4zA0A0DB2AWUcovGZUGkC267EDLUk4CpeDw6KfqlRWwHXUh71DhjKZQeRTLDqSTdFUsJlECo9cGYmd6s1slKrVbjb0SirPkq88n/AMEx3dhv3gLPLQeT/wCCY7uw37wE6IELmh16oDvCzr9T3okqpqe8pCEt2aJaCl+BV/8AE4L1GMWfWgp/gOI/xOC/d8YhWHgPEeqpyUSGZJzKwQlZkEUoZkKZS2vhBzpSMyPMogKbxiJwSg86KVgqhEqDmTjKsaFQ5shMoVtG8OxgKe58qJVqGdURxPYE1mCoynGadaLUHgXeyXzh4oy8pqQjkdiZAWU1HbVLbXBRlyhEhHn3SlmnsWkWwx8yXUdJQznimpSsyYGgLMahJmUrMkyk5kJUqpM5owtDsL8Ex35uH/eWrPSr7YJ+9Md+Zh/3lig5IBgjiFQVNT3lNynKup7ykKoUP8R4pKutmbfrYfMKL3sz5M4aWw40wQ0kFp0zHxKpUEQhriP8B68VpvbtjPhqniz7CHt2xnw1Txp/YVDQpAgzNuG+xMaa2TpwoHE9IDxA6XdqiAraR276W9lc+3bGfD1f1mfYQ9uuM+Hrfrt+wqYYdsbzbcdTBJABCU7CNG8npNHjE7v6kIgI0rt30t7K29uuM+MVv12/ZRe3TGfGK/zg+yqn2O2R1iCJB082nn86UMGIE5pgSOEx2WRAUaR276W9lae3TGfGK/zg+yj9uuM+MVv12/ZVFzVt/wBHpSOZdw9CICnSO3fS3stD7dcZ8PV/Xb9hH7d8Z8NV/WZ9hVPsNtutH9ADSxuPpSfYrfyuqD55NtNdLdvmRARpXbvpb2Vx7d8Z8NU8af2Eft4xnwz/ABp/y1T+xGxPS0B100t1e3+tyDhW3AN92l5aCPpIUo0rt30t7K79vGM+Ff8A6X8tD28Yz4V/+l/LVQcEyY6XiL66W7E3UwzRGuonzzbTXT+tBGldu+lvZXft3xnwz/8AS/loe3fF/Cv8KX8tUJojMRcgA7xuE6xZOnCtk9bx1uY9z2HSVEI0h2DkOyuPbtjPhXfq0f5aP264v4U/qUP5apThBJAPd29e2nFvpSKtAAWkncZEQSY3cO1EI0h2DkOyu/blivhB8zhj/wCtNYzynr1WOpvf0HZcwbSoszZSHAEsYCRIB13KhNMjckIhGk3DknHmSSkSiQUqhMoylCOBSSiQoUugxk3PCL9/9edKpllpjxdwaePGVCQQhTYpx2QLz0pjhPn77IOYzcRqN+7N38CPAprD3OkgcBJUkFp9wQYvANrns3z9AQhJIpxYN00JNjaBr3yiLWbsuu8+5gTrvlOOrNtqIIk5dRaRPh4ImkNguDt94PF0C4vIdPghCR0PybjtkOjhw396SQzNuiBb/f8ArVKrOBIsbHSDOgiR5knLpFjuOUjzz5kISm5N+XXs06XA/m6IMFON0wJnsifSfBPB4mcrjeR0Ta0W43M/pcUhjgZEOvFgDpABFu6B5+KEKPUa3PYjLI8LJ8tp36vZfdbW/GUKrQeiA5pMHLlM2zGwGuv0InRuBbeYLTcACJjdv/SQhANpTujdrxNj3AfSEl1Nl7jsgzqXRv0u0+ZJeDPVMGYJaZM6d9ynOeAHSBNoII3xEzu0IQhN1SzcPdcbkSbdg0S8lMxoNJgyQI79ZR86BrI6U6EdGZy+f+AS6RBghp9zbKSOi6T36whCZys7NBF7TffO+B47kpwp8G6aybGHT7q94TktGrHDTdugSO2A0HxUHmnROUxE6HTihClZGfk6e+91HVN9O3jw0QinazdBNzr0p39ygoIQlvIJsIHDVIQRoQiS8p4FIU8420X3cPc6R4BCFCynglsc4aT4KQcZO8/5fqRnGzaXR+j9SEJIr2MgkkR3GHCfpTxxY1yu1kGB77MO7emzju13+X6kVTGAgjpX7kIT1LEWJbTJGadCQJABBI7FGr5ne4IuTpuIAHoSKeIc0QDbtAOuvoTp2hU4+n60IUl2Ni7qZGsbrnj5o8E3RxQbBDXGDI75cb+YhRa+Jc+M25NteRoSEIU8Yoa82d1t0NdmjTt+hEMYYjIetmnf18x3dw8yhc673x8SiznifFCE+15zB2U2aBH6GX/dSPZhtDHRJN76uDju01HgoPOO4nxKLOeJ8UIUuhiYblyE2IJGtzNjFtU57LJEFpIFr8OkDJ32cfOSoAeeJQznifFCE9VqOkkAidbb9CT33TnssREGxB3ah08OCil54lIQhTmY0ANhtwQdd4Zl4edSsJmrlzKdO5bxADRpMxpoFTqx2PtI0HExIcII39hCEIsXsx9M5dXXmNBEGAd5giyjjCVPeHw/rip+1Nsc7lAbDWnNe5cTrPYoXsv8kfT9aEJh7CDBEFBEZKEoQjCJyCCEJKCCCEIIIIIQgggghCCCCCEIIIIIQgggghCCCCCEIIIIIQgggghCCCCCEJwJtBBCF//Z" class="img-responsive" alt="Dead Poets Society movie poster">
          </div>
    </div>
</div><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you aren't nesting your rows and columns correctly.

Simplified, you want a pattern like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">Column 1 of 4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Column 2 of 4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Column 3 of 4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Column 4 of 4</div>
</div>
```

Your code simplified looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">Column 1 of 4</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">Column 2 of 4</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">Column 3 of 4</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">Column 4 of 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See how you're putting a new row inside of a row? You want to only have the one row tag that CONTAINS your columns for that row. Not setting another row within a row.

Sure, you can put a row within a column, but based on your question I don't think that is the behavior you are desiring.